# How to put several elements column wise- not douplicated

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on a numpy array as following:

```
A= np.array([[ 0,  9, 18, 27,  1, 10, 19, 28,  2, 11, 20, 29],
       [ 3, 12, 21, 30,  4, 13, 22, 31,  5, 14, 23, 32],
       [ 6, 15, 24, 33,  7, 16, 25, 34,  8, 17, 26, 35]])
```

I want to create the following array using the above :

```
B = np.array([[ 0,  9, 18],
       [ 3, 12, 21],
       [ 6, 15, 24],
       [27,  1, 10],
       [30,  4, 13],
       [33,  7, 16],
       [19, 28,  2],
       [22, 31,  5],
       [25, 34,  8],
       [11, 20, 29],
       [14, 23, 32],
       [17, 26, 35]])
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: `B = A.reshape((12, 3))`

Comment: No. this is not the same as you told (B = A.reshape((12, 3)))